# Is there a way to download my flutter app to IOS without a developer account

Tags: flutter, ipa

I have built my first flutter app and would like to download it on my iphone. I have researched the topic a bit, but have failed to find a solution. I can test it when my phone is connected to my computer but cannot  use it without. Thanks

I have tried debugging it using —release. I have tried to create an ipa file using terminal, but got an error since i dont have a developer account.

Comment: As far as I know, Apple doesn't allow that

Comment: Nope, the  monopoly demands that you use their hardware and os, whether you rent it, buy it (or steal it). It's all about controlling their revenue stream and keeping their shareholders very happy.